# Send SimpleForm data to email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a SimpleForm in my Rails application, and I want the data typed into the fields to send to an email address when my user clicks the "Submit" button. How would I go about doing this?

```
<%= simple_form_for @category, :url => url_for(:action => 'bookfinal', :controller => 'users'), :method => 'post' do |f| %>

<%= f.text_field :address1, :size=>"40", placeholder: 'Street number, street name' %> <br>

<%= f.text_field :address2, :size=>"40", placeholder: 'Apt/Suite No' %><br>

<%= f.text_field :citystate, :size=>"40", placeholder: 'City/State/Province' %><br>

<%= f.text_field :country, :size=>"40", placeholder: 'Country' %><br>

     <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: Use ActionMailer (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) to send email. The code to do that can be placed on `bookfinal` action at `users`  controller

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) in your action. For example,

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def bookfinal(options)
    mail(to: "customer@example.com", subject: "Thanks")
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def bookfinal
    # you may want to save shipping data to db first
    UserMailer.bookfinal(params_you_want_to_pass).deliver_now
  end
end
```

Good luck :)